# Visual Studio code shortcut to find classes and methods?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut in Visual studio **Code** (Or an extension for it)?.

I use to use PHPstorm, there was a function that you can find the classes directly, by clicking on it. When I use visual studio code you need to search all files.

Answer (score 0):

shortcut: `ctrl + p`

This will behave just like the 'double-spacebar' of JetBrains products.

Answer (score -1):

This should work with the **PHP IntelliSense** extension:

PHP 7 installation is required.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-intellisense